# Troca de arquivo .phtml na mudança de opção (Admin magento)

Tags: xml, magento

Tenho um modulo que estou fazendo e tenho uma dúvida, segue:

O meu *custom_module.xml* está asssim:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="root">
    <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>customizefooter/footer.phtml</template>
            </action>
            </block>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

Ao ser habilitado a opção *Yes* ou *No* dentro da configuração `ADMIN` do meu módulo, ele habilita:

```
<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('my_module/options/enable_custom_paradox_html')): ?>
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('my_module/options/Html_double_paradox'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>`
```

Beleza, com o *Yes* habilitado ele carrega a minha nova opção junto com o arquivo setado no `setTemplate` e as opções que nele foram definidas.

Mas quando eu seleciono a opção *NÃO*, ele não retorna para o arquivo .phtml original, continua no meu e com a opção desmarcada. Eu preciso que quando seja selecionado a opção *NÃO* ele mude o .phtml para o *custom padrão* e somente quando a opção *SIM* estiver habilitada carregue o meu .phtml.

Como procedo? Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

De uma pesquisada sobre o **ifconfig** do xml do magento, é uma condição se estiver **yes** ele executa.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="my_module/options/enable_custom_paradox_html">
                <template>customizefooter/footer.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

**Obs:** Não consigo testar com as informações que você passou, então fica a dica do **ifconfig** só funciona na **action**.

Todos meus módulos eu utilizo, caso queria consultar alguns exemplos:
[http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=dexxtz&pl=0](http://bit.ly/modules-dexxtz)

Utilize o [freegento](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) para baixar o código fonte.